# Entity Framework .NET 8 Save Data as JSON Object

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I want to save data in SQL Server like this:

```
Preparation : 
    [
        "reviewCustomerDataBeforeVisit": "5", 
        "setSmartObjectivesForVisit": "5",          
        "complaintHandlingPlan": "5"
    ]
```

- Is it possible?
- Or is there any other way?
- Or, in the code-first, what should I do?

This is my entity:

```
namespace Msfa.Api.Entities
{
    public class InfieldCoaching
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? InfieldCoachingId { get; set; }
        public Preparation Preparation { get; set; }
        public Opening Opening { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Preparation
    {
        [Range(1, 5)]
        public int? ReviewCustomerDataBeforeVisit { get; set; }
        [Range(1, 5)]
        public int? SetSmartObjectivesForVisit { get; set; }
        [Range(1, 5)]
        public int? ComplaintHandlingPlan { get; set; }
    }

    public class Opening
    {
        [Range(1, 5)]
        public int? CreateCustomerAttention { get; set; }
        [Range(1, 5)]
        public int? ProductVisibilityChecked { get; set; }
        [Range(1, 5)]
        public int? StockLevelsCounted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my `POST` request from Swagger based on that entity:

```
{
  "preparation": {
    "reviewCustomerDataBeforeVisit": 5,
    "setSmartObjectivesForVisit": 5,
    "complaintHandlingPlan": 5
  },
  "opening": {
    "createCustomerAttention": 5,
    "productVisibilityChecked": 5,
    "stockLevelsCounted": 5
  },
  "managers": [
    "string"
  ]
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: If you are looking for JSON column, it is [available from EF7](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/02/14/getting-started-entity-framework-core-7-json-support/). Without JSON column, the entities will be stored in the different tables. Meanwhile, your provided `Preparation` data is not a valid JSON object, an object should be wrapped with `{}` but not `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this solution **[Getting Started: Entity Framework Core 7 JSON Support](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/02/14/getting-started-entity-framework-core-7-json-support/)**;

I add these on **`ApplicationDbContext`**:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<InfieldCoaching>()
        .OwnsOne(p => p.Preparation, builder => { builder.ToJson(); })
        .OwnsOne(p => p.Opening, builder => { builder.ToJson(); });
}
```

Using: **EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.0**